# ODataController BearerToken Authorization denied

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, owin

I'm trying to implement an Authentication Provider for my WebApi Services.
Im using this guide: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/
For testing purpose i've implemented two controllers in a separate webapi-project:

```
public class TestApiController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Secure";
    }

    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "Not Secure";
    }
} 

public class TestODataController : ODataController
{
    [Authorize]
    [EnableQuery]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
       return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK); 
    }
}
```

My Goal is to use the Odata Controller in the end.

When I call **localhost:Port/api/TestApi** and set the Bearer Token in the Header, everythings works fine. When i do the call **localhost:Port/odata/TestOData** and add the token i receive the Message :

> Authorization has been denied for this request.

It doesn't matter if i set the token in header or not. If i remove the *Authorize* Attribute everything works fine.
I'm using Postman to call the methods, if this is of any interest.
At the moment i'm using iis-express from visual studio to host the controllers, but iis is alread configured but produces the same message.

My Startup.cs (the interesting part...)

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    ConfigureOAuth(app);

    FilterConfig.Register(config);
    ODataConfig.Register(config);
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);

    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}

public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //Token consumption
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {});
}
```

OData and WebConfig :

```
public class ODataConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.EntitySet<MyModel>("MyModel");

        var conventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();

        var route = config.Routes.MapODataRouteFixed(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "odata",
            model: modelBuilder.GetEdmModel(),
            conventions: conventions) as Route;
    }
}

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

The Account-Controller to add new user is in another project. The database looks good and the token generation works, too. It's almost the same code as the example from *bitoftech-demo*.

I don't see the difference betweens these controllers. The Auhtorize attribute is recognized by the controller...but something else is wrong.
Any hints would be appreciated.

**Update**
After some research and the first answers i updated my startup values. The old options are only necessary for token generation and not token consumption. But still api controllers works and OdataController throws "Authorization denied".

**Update2**
It worked now. But i'm not quite sure why. I removed everything from my *FilterConfig* :

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        //config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
    }
}
```

But i have no idea why it was working before with the api controller and not with the odata controller...

Answer (score 0):

If you use one project for getting the token and another for webApi, both must have the same machine key in web.config.

In the next post of the same serial that you are following explains how to do it: [Decouple OWIN Authorization Server from Resource Server](http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/)

Example:

```
<system.web>
...
<machineKey validationKey="57B449BBA8F9E656087FF7848727E122C5F5966F65AC0FC25FB3532193B59CFCD13B370883FFC184C1F1500638F33E6F67B37CAED1D9BC65BBC6CFFB232BFD0B" decryptionKey="6D9FBE88D16B3FA5B5E6B37460BBE50DA85D5B4C482159006B5A337C58AA9E79" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
...
</system.web>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The two projects (Authentication and WebApi with the two controllers) are, at the moment, in one Solution on the same machine. If something was wrong with the token, the ApiController shouldn't work either. Or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: @dope85 Even if they are in the same solution, if they are in different projects you have to set the same value for machinekey tag in web.config file. In other case the way the token is created in the autorization process it will be different of the way is decrypting to be validated in you web api controllers.

Comment: @Freerider No need to unify mahcineKey in web.config if the projects are in the same machine, they will work and will use machine.config not web.config

Comment: Hi, I've added the machine key element in both configs. Stil same Error: ApiController works, ODataController returns "Authorization has been denied for this request."

Comment: @TaiseerJoudeh Of course you can configure the machineKey tag at computer level (machine.config) and at IIS level (aspnet.config). In these cases all projects in the same computer will share the machineKey, however is a common mistake to configure the machineKey tag only in the Authorization Server web.config, wich makes webApi in other projects not authenticate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());` and `app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);` on the same time, I guess this is only API project with no MVC, right?
Remove the `app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);` and try again.

What is the value in response header (WWW-Authenticate) when you receive 401? Bearer or something else?

Comment: After removing the line, still the same Error. I thought it it was an additional option to use cookies AND Bearer. Not one of them. The Headers from Postman: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Cache-Control → no-cache
Content-Length → 97
Content-Type → application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
Date → Thu, 09 Apr 2015 05:53:14 GMT
Expires → -1
OData-Version → 4.0
Pragma → no-cache
Server → Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version → 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By → ASP.NET` and the body `{
"error": {
"code": "",
"message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and found this answer posted on Telerik web site and it worked for me. It required setting the dataType to "json".

```
transport: {
    type: "odata",
     read: {
         url: "http://........",
         dataType: "json",
         beforeSend: function (xhr) {
             var auth = 'Bearer ' + token;
             xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
         }
     },

 },
```

This is the url:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/odata-not-working-with-custom-authorization-header

Comment: Remember to format code by selecting the text and pressing the {} button in the toolbar, it makes reading code much easier.